# Tabs content active while scroll from div and also active relevant tab

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to change tabs on scroll. For example when user scroll to div#tab-scroll and center of the screen. The tabs inside this div active on scroll. First tab active and user scroll then 2nd tab
active and shows its content and so on.

I added custom tabs code to show the structure works on the website.

```js
jQuery(function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $(window).scroll(function(){
        var scrollPos = $(window).scrollTop();
        var elementPos = $('#tab-scroll').offset().top;
        var windowHeight = $(window).height();
    
    var sectionName = $('#tab-scroll .tab-content-section .tab-content').attr('id');        
        var navigationMatch = $('#tab-scroll .tab-container .tab[aria-controls="' + sectionName + '"]');
    
        if (elementPos > scrollPos + (windowHeight / 3) && elementPos < scrollPos + (windowHeight / 2)) {         
      navigationMatch.addClass('active');       
        }
    else {
      navigationMatch.removeClass('active');
    }
      });
    });
});
```

```css
 .content-0{
    height: 500px;
    background: #ff4;
  }
 .tab-container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
  }
  .tab {
    margin: 0 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  }
  .tab.active {
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #f0f0f0;
  }
  .tab-content {
    display: none;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
  }
  .tab-content.active {
    display: block;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Tab Example</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="content-0"></div>
<div id="tab-scroll">
  <div class="tab-container">
    <div class="tab" aria-controls="tab1">Tab 1</div>
    <div class="tab" aria-controls="tab2">Tab 2</div>
    <div class="tab" aria-controls="tab3">Tab 3</div>
  </div>

  <div class="tab-content-section">
    <div id="tab1" class="tab-content active" aria-labelledby="tab1">
      <h2>Tab 1 Content</h2>
      <p>This is the content of Tab 1.</p>
    </div>

    <div id="tab2" class="tab-content" aria-labelledby="tab2">
      <h2>Tab 2 Content</h2>
      <p>This is the content of Tab 2.</p>
    </div>

    <div id="tab3" class="tab-content" aria-labelledby="tab3">
      <h2>Tab 3 Content</h2>
      <p>This is the content of Tab 3.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script>
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  var tabs = document.querySelectorAll('.tab');
  tabs.forEach(function (tab) {
    tab.addEventListener('click', function () {
      var tabId = this.getAttribute('aria-controls');
      var tabContent = document.getElementById(tabId);
      if (!tabContent) return;
      
      var activeTabs = document.querySelectorAll('.tab-content.active');
      activeTabs.forEach(function (activeTab) {
        activeTab.classList.remove('active');
      });
      
      var activeTabLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.tab.active');
      activeTabLinks.forEach(function (activeTabLink) {
        activeTabLink.classList.remove('active');
      });
      
      tabContent.classList.add('active');
      this.classList.add('active');
    });
  });
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm not really getting what you are asking here?